# Algunas dudas con materialize

Tags: html, html5, css3, material-design, materialize

bueno al final pude hacer mi web responsiva, yo pensaba que esas cosas se hacían manualmente, y resulta que existian framework ufff, bueno en fin, tengo algunas dudas que me quedaron pendientes:

Por ejemplo en mis formularios cuando tengo campos de texto u otras cosas, como "checkbox" al presionarlos se ponen de color verde, como puedo cambiar eso?

Aquí les dejo una imagen para que vean de que hablo:

[image: Materialize login verde]

```
<form method="POST" class="col s12 m12 l12 offset-l0 m0 s0 white blue-text" name="formulario"> <!-- Tamano del form responsive, color de texto y de fondo-->  
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="input-field col s12 m12 l12"> <!-- Tamano del input-field Titulo-->
                        <i class="material-icons prefix waves-effect waves-light-blue lighten-1">perm_identity</i>
                        <input id="icon_prefix" type="email" class="validate" name="txtCorreo">
                        <label for="icon_prefix">Correo</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                            <div class="row">
                    <div class="input-field col s12 m12 l12"> <!-- Tamano del input-field Titulo-->
                        <i class="material-icons prefix">lock_outline</i>
                        <input id="icon_prefix" type="password" class="validate" name="txtPassword">
                        <label for="icon_prefix">Contraseña</label>
                    </div>
                </div>


             <div class="row">
               <div class="input-field col s12 m12 l12 center"> <!-- Tamano del boton enviar-->
                          <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light blue" type="submit" name="action" class="submit">Acceder
                          <i class="material-icons right">send</i></button>
                       </div>
                    </div>


            </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Digamos que tu proyecto está dentro de una carpeta *Sistema*, y en ella creaste una carpeta *html* en la que colocaste tu html, digamos que se llama *login.html*. Entonces el archivo está en `Sistema/html/login.html`.

En el mismo archivo tienes tus inputs y demás, por ejemplo:

```
<html>
  <head> ... </head>
  <body>
    ...
      <div class="input-field col s12 m12 l12">
        <i class="material-icons prefix">perm_identity</i>
        <input id="icon_prefix" type="email" class="validate" name="txtCorreo">
        <label for="icon_prefix">Correo</label>
      </div>
    ...
  </body>
</html>
```

Para cambiar los colores que quieres, puedes usar los CSS que te entrega directamente [Materialize - Sección: Changing colors](http://materializecss.com/forms.html). Esto lo puedes lograr creando un nuevo archivo CSS, que se llame por ejemplo `estilos.css` y agregarle el siguiente contenido:

```
/* Este cambia el color del label del campo cuando no está seleccionado */
.input-field label {
  color: #000; /* Donde dice #000 pones el color que quieres */
}

/* Este es para cambiar el color del label cuando seleccionas el campo */
.input-field input[type=text]:focus + label {
  color: blue; /* Por ejemplo, acá saco el verde y pongo por azul */
}

/* Este es para cambiar el color de la línea del campo cuando lo seleccionas */
.input-field input[type=text]:focus {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000; /* El #000 es el color de la línea */
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #000; /* Y acá, de la pequeña sombra que genera */
}

/* Si usas la propiedad validate, el color de la línea al validar, será este */
.input-field input[type=text].valid {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #000;
}

/* Y este será el color en el caso que se tome como inválido */
.input-field input[type=text].invalid {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 black;
}

/* Pôr último, este cambia el color al ícono cuando entras a un campo */
.input-field .prefix.active {
  color: blue; /* También quieres cambiar esto a otro color, o no? */
}
```

Ahora, lo único que queda para que puedas ver los colores, es decirle a tu archivo HTML que quieres que use cierto archivo CSS para darle colores a tu página. Esto es algo que ya hiciste al agregar Materialize dentro de la etiqueta *head*, ahora tienes que hacer lo mismo, pero con tu nuevo archivo.

Digamos que creaste tu archivo *estilos.css* dentro de `Sistema/css/estilos.css`
Lo que deberías modificar en tu archivo login.html es agregar una línea dentro del head:

```
<html>
  <head>
    ...
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/estilos.css">
    ...
  </head>
  <body> ... </body>
</html>
```

En el caso que uses Sass y no CSS, puedes lograr lo mismo, como se describe un poco en [Materialize - Sass](http://materializecss.com/sass.html), haciendo:

```
$secondary-color: color("A", "B") !default;
```

Siendo **A** un color, por ejemplo *red* y **B** una de las variaciones del color, por ejemplo *lighten-3*. La paleta de colores y variaciones permitidas están en [Materialize - Colors](http://materializecss.com/color.html). En el caso que quieras usar alguno que no se encuentre en la lista, simplemente haces `$secondary-color: #4f2caa !default;`

Nota: Para elegir el color puro sin ninguna variación, en B simplemente colocas *base*.

Comment: Ese código lo vi, pero no se si tengo que modificar los archivos de materialize o crear un nuevo css?

Comment: Simplemente creas un archivo CSS y le cambias lo que gustes. En este caso, los colores. Luego desde el html donde pones los inputs referencias a ese archivo CSS que creaste. No tienes que cambiar nada de Materialize.

Comment: perfecto! muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Para colorear los botones o cualquier tipo de elementos de materialize utiliza alguna de sus clases

```html
<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn">button</a>
<a class="waves-effect waves-light-blue lighten-1 btn">button</a>
<a class="waves-effect waves-light-green darken-4 btn">button</a>
<a class="waves-effect waves-light-orange lighten-3 btn">button</a>
```

El color default de btn es el verde que miras ahora

[Más sobre clases y colores](http://materializecss.com/color.html)

Comment: voy a poner mi code editando la pregunta, porque no se donde incluir tu código dentro del mio, lo que yo quiero es que cuando tu presionar sobre una caja de texto el icono y el texto NO se pongan verdes

Answer (score 0):

Lo que estas buscando es invalidar el comportamiento de una clase CSS que tienes puesta (o se pone por Javascript) en tu `html`.

- Si sabes de que clase se trata, eliminala de la maquetación y ya no tendrá efecto.
- Si no lo sabes, o no estás seguro de qué clase es, inspecciona los elementos *verdes* con el navegador (F12) y entre las reglas que tiene aplicadas verás cual es la que le está pintando de ese color no deseado.

Lo más recomendable sería que reproducieras un **breve** ejemplo reeditando tu pregunta donde se viera el comportamiento que comentas y así, si podríamos indicarte exactamente qué regla es y como solucionarlo.

Answer (score 0):

He sacado de cada respuesta un poco y me ha servido para dar con lo puntual. Mi solución fue hacer esto en un nuevo archivo .css

colores.css

---

```
.input-field .prefix.active {
  color: #64b5f6;
}

input:not([type]):focus:not([readonly]) + label,
input[type=text]:not(.browser-default):focus:not([readonly]) + label,
input[type=password]:not(.browser-default):focus:not([readonly]) + label,
input[type=email]:not(.browser-default):focus:not([readonly]) + label,
input[type=url]:not(.browser-default):focus:not([readonly]) + label,
input[type=time]:not(.browser-default):focus:not([readonly]) + label,
input[type=date]:not(.browser-default):focus:not([readonly]) + label,
input[type=datetime]:not(.browser-default):focus:not([readonly]) + label,
input[type=datetime-local]:not(.browser-default):focus:not([readonly]) + label,
input[type=tel]:not(.browser-default):focus:not([readonly]) + label,
input[type=number]:not(.browser-default):focus:not([readonly]) + label,
input[type=search]:not(.browser-default):focus:not([readonly]) + label,
textarea.materialize-textarea:focus:not([readonly]) + label {
  color: #64b5f6;}

input:not([type]):focus:not([readonly]),
input[type=text]:not(.browser-default):focus:not([readonly]),
input[type=password]:not(.browser-default):focus:not([readonly]),
input[type=email]:not(.browser-default):focus:not([readonly]),
input[type=url]:not(.browser-default):focus:not([readonly]),
input[type=time]:not(.browser-default):focus:not([readonly]),
input[type=date]:not(.browser-default):focus:not([readonly]),
input[type=datetime]:not(.browser-default):focus:not([readonly]),
input[type=datetime-local]:not(.browser-default):focus:not([readonly]),
input[type=tel]:not(.browser-default):focus:not([readonly]),
input[type=number]:not(.browser-default):focus:not([readonly]),
input[type=search]:not(.browser-default):focus:not([readonly]),
textarea.materialize-textarea:focus:not([readonly]) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #64b5f6;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #64b5f6;
          box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #64b5f6;
}
```

---

Espero haber ayudado :)